# is there any way to control 'style.xml' elements in java section?

Tags: java, android

Hi I'm trying to make simple Android app.
I want to make my app changing it's **font** depending on the language of users.

but I don't know how to change `<item>` in `styles.xml`.

I set font at `values/styles.xml` like below

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/Customfont1</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/Customfont2</item>
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/Customfont3</item>
  </style>

  <style name="Customfont1" parent="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.TextView">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/bmjua</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
        <item name="android:textAlignment">center</item>
```

and need to change

`<item name="android:fontFamily">@font/bmjua</item>`  part to
`<item name="android:fontFamily">@font/roundbold</item>`

when local language is Japanese.

I use code below

```
Locale syslocal = getApplicationContext().getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
        String curLanguate = ((Locale) syslocal).getLanguage();
```

to get local language code and  What I can't do now is

```
'if(curLanguate=="ja"){

  "change  '<item name="android:fontFamily">@font/bmjua</item> ' to 
           '<item name="android:fontFamily">@font/roundbold</item> '
by changing'styles.xml'file.
}
```

what I have to do? to make this possible?!

Comment: Create locale specific xml values as described [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages).

Comment: I solve it my self... just don't need to use java but at res folder, I can make as many xml for foreign languages.